# vba Excel do while user input

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on some VBA scripting for Excel and having some trouble. What I'm trying to do let the user select a set of columns to concatonate. So, i would use Application.InputBox in a loop to store the column headers as a range, then take that range to format a concatonate() formula.

E.g.: the user wants to concatonate the contents of colum d, e, a (in that order). The InputBox would continue to appear until the user clicked cancel, storing the range (the column header such as d1, e1, a1) in an array from which I can build the concatonate statement.

I've spent some time with this and am stumped. My first hurdle is that I can't seem to get a while loop that ends when the InputBox returns false (user presses "cancel").

Any help would be really appreciated. Having a C based background, I'm really struggling with VBA...

Comment: do some efforts/show your code

Comment: My apologies on the lack of code. There's a few ways I tried to do this:

Comment: My apologies on the lack of code. I did give it some some time before posting - I should have shared the code I had. I'll be mindful in future posts to show my efforts. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though you did not provide any code try doing this...

```
Dim concatCells()
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

msgselect = MsgBox("Please select the cell you wish to concatenate.", vbOKCancel)

Do While msgselect = vbOK
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve concatCells(i)
    concatCells(i - 1) = Application.InputBox("select cell", Type:=8)
    msgselect = MsgBox("Please select the cell you wish to concatenate.", vbOKCancel)
Loop

Dim rangeToConcat As String
For i = 0 To UBound(concatCells)
    rangeToConcat = rangeToConcat & concatCells(i)
Next i
Range("A1").Formula = rangeToConcat
```

Comment: If you want it to do the full column you would need to nest the for loop I have with another one starting at row 1 to last used row.

Comment: Perfect - thanks. Apologies again for the lack of code. Appreciate the help.